# Capturing CGRect does not give proper image. What to do?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am capturing CGRect with following code. But the resulting image is not the image what i want. Image has some transparent background. What to do for removing transparent background as suggesting the picture[image].

```
   - (UIImage *)captureScreenInRect:(CGRect)captureFrame {

        CALayer *layer;
        layer = imageScrollview.layer;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageScrollview.bounds.size); 
        CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),captureFrame);
        \[layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()\];
        UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return screenImage;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate your context so that its origin matches your `captureFrame`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageScrollview.bounds.size);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -captureFrame.origin.x, -captureFrame.origin.y);
[imageScrollView.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

(written from memory, untested)

Additionally clipping the context is not necessary as the image is already clipped by the image context's bounds.

Comment: Still not capturing properly. I guess i am doing something wrong with scrollview or context. Thanks omz for reply.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
CGRect  cropRect = CGRectMake(imageScrollview.frame.origin.x+15, imageScrollview.frame.origin.y+15, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Comment: Are you serious? You should find out why there are 15 px of space in the first place, not just hack them away. The image is probably not in the top left of the image view causing you to capture the extra space around it. Next time you use this code somewhere else you will get totally incorrect results.

Comment: Actually i have same problem and fixed with this hack so just paste it over here and may its fixed DipakSonara's problem..lets see...

Comment: : @MikeWeller  Yes my problem is fixed with Paras Gandhi's code and may be this is hack but it works fine. If you better solution then paste over here.